# SAS DI Stop job if dataset is populated

Tags: sas, sas-dis

I'm quite new to SAS and really can't get my head around it's code, so asking here for help.

I've a job that is reading an external csv file, and have a macro created by a colleague that validates the data in this external file and prints out error message to a work table.

What I'd like to do is either on precode of the file reader, or by using another user written code transformation is to read the work table and check if observations exist, and if they do, abort the job. From googling, and between here and SAS community, I can find how to read a dataset and count observations but I'm having real difficulty in figuring out how to implement it so any guidance would be really appreciated

Can anyone please help me on this?

Thanks

Comment: Look at using an UPDATE procedure rather than automatic insert procedure. UPDATE and MODIFY statements are possible approaches.

Comment: I'm assuming you're using SAS DI studio and not Base SAS?

Comment: Yup, using DI Studio. I've got the external file, a file reader transformation and then going into the SAS table. User Written Code macro is separate

Comment: There aren't a lot of DI people on here, you can post on communities.sas.com if that's ok, more SAS DI users there as well as the SAS developers.